# Changing size of the frame and elements in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, resize, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to know if there is a way to resize the frame and the elements inside of it when the window size change. I always want to have the same proportion in the size of the elements inside the frame.

Example:

1- Windowsize = 100(in x) and Imagesize = 50(in x) locationx = 25

2- Windowsize = 50(in x) and Imagesize = 25(in x) location x = 12.5(~12)

In this case, the windowsize is "something", imagesize is 1/2 of "something" and locationx of the image is 1/4 of something. I wan't to do something like this but with every element inside the frame.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<ViewBox/>` control which does exactly that.

```
<Page>...
<Grid>
    <ViewBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="test" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text="some text"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ViewBox>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

In the example below, the `ViewBox` is placed inside a Grid and stretched both Horizontally and Vertically which causes it to stretch with the Page resize.

Reference docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox.aspx).

Comment: If I understand, the `ViewBox` resizes a single child. To address the OP's question, this child would have to be a compound (probably one of the [Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel.aspx) implementations). This answer would be more complete if it provided a small XAML snippet, that outlines, how to set up the child.

Comment: But don't change the elements size

Comment: @IInspectable, yes you can put them inside a Grid or any other Panel that you need.

Comment: @Onelio I don't understand your comment. Do you need them to resize or not ?

Comment: Yes, I need to resize the window and the elements inside of it like a textblock, make it smaller

Comment: check my latest edit on the post. Should be what you're looking for if I got the question right